# floating action button ripple doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I am having trouble achieving a ripple effect on my floating action button
i have followed exactly what it says online but i cant see the ripple effect

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/new_chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add_chat"
            android:tooltipText="Start a new chat"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="56dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/pastel_red" />
```

Answer (score -1):

add this to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="SelectableItemTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/pastel_red</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableItemBackground">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>  #this makes it round, if you want square, remove the word "Borderless"
</style>
```

And then

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:id="@+id/new_chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add_chat"
            android:tooltipText="Start a new chat"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="56dp" />
```